Is it possible to index CSV file name without extension + literal string + CSV field value in Azure AI search?
I have CSV files on Azure Blob Storage which contain a field Type (among other fields). I use indexer parsing mode delimitedText to split them into documents - one per row. The AI enrichment tree for such a document should contain the node /document/Type.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage when indexing Azure Blobs one also gets metadata nodes like /document/metadata_storage_name and /document/metadata_storage_path.
For example, suppose I have a file xyz.csv and there is a record inside with Type = abc. Then this record presumably (I think) will have /document/Type = "abc" and /document/metadata_storage_name = "xyz.csv" in the AI enrichment tree.
Assuming I get it so far, can I somehow generate a new field for the index that would combine the file name without the extension and the type using a certain literal string to separate the two?
In my example I would like this field to have the value of abc @ xyz.
Can it be done without a custom skill?

To achieve without custom skill set you need to use MergeSkill, SplitSkill and a mapping function extractTokenAtPosition to get only the file name without extension.
First, create 2 new fields filename and combinedText, both are of string type.
Next, in indexer definition you add the mapping function in field mappings like below. This extracts only filename.
"fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "AzureSearch_DocumentKey",
      "targetFieldName": "AzureSearch_DocumentKey",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
      "targetFieldName": "filename",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "extractTokenAtPosition",
        "parameters": {
          "delimiter": ".",
          "position": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],

Refer about this here.
Use text split skill to convert this string to array of string.
Since it is the type accepted by merge skill.
Create a skill set like below.
{
  "name": "skillset1725958890028",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/filename"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "arrayresult"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "name": "CombineFieldsSkill",
      "description": "Combines multiple fields into a single string",
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": "@",
      "insertPostTag": "",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/Type"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert",
          "source": "/document/arrayresult"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText",
          "targetName": "combined_field"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices"
  }
}

Add output field mappings in indexer to populate the results.
Below is the full indexer definition.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xyx.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCD17A4933D27D\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds",
  "skillsetName": "skillset1725958890028",
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "delimitedText",
      "firstLineContainsHeaders": true,
      "delimitedTextDelimiter": ",",
      "delimitedTextHeaders": ""
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "AzureSearch_DocumentKey",
      "targetFieldName": "AzureSearch_DocumentKey",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
      "targetFieldName": "filename",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "extractTokenAtPosition",
        "parameters": {
          "delimiter": ".",
          "position@odata.type": "#Int64",
          "position": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/combined_field",
      "targetFieldName": "combinedText"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Output:


I am in the process of creating the data source, so it will take me some time to test your code. You seem to have been able to test it very quickly. Do you mind sharing your setup? This way I could verify your answer faster. Thank you very much.

You can use the same indexer and skillset definition but index is depends on your data. I have just tried with csv file having Type as column and it's value.

I have the data source ready. Will work to test your answer. Just to make sure - the file name may contain dots, like abc.def.csv. I just need to get rid of the .csv extension.

I do not think this solution works when the file name contains dots. The file names denote assembly names. And so dots are common there. It seems your solution takes only the first part of the name up to the first dot.

Ok then try using  .csv as delimiter and extract first part.

Hmm, I do not see any option to specify a delimiter to the SplitSkill task. It is either split by pages or by sentences without letting us customize the delimiter. Or am I missing anything?

Yes you are missing something. extractTokenAtPosition is mapping function used in indexer field mappings. Please check that i have given that in starting.

Oh, right. The mapping function allows to specify the delimiter. Got it.
